# Rotate labels on HighCharts WindRose plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, rotation, label

Highcharts is being used to create a windrose plot of correlation coefficient between one variable and many others. The default placement of the labels is such that they cannot be read near the top and bottom of the plot. I would like to rotate them such that they read like rays coming out of the center. Using the PlotOptions:rotate option, all labels rotate the same amount but I need each label to rotate by a slightly different angle. How can I achieve this? Thank you all for your kind help!

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of that ?

Comment: I just had a similar question answered here. Your's is essentially a pie, but you have a little bit of a gotcha on the centerpoint alignment on the weighted slice, but it may be helpful anyways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676246/radial-pie-chart-datalabels-in-highcharts

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm not allowed to post an image here. I uploaded one here: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/rotate-labels-on-highcharts-windrose-plot-t34304/?sid=d63f43de32d2a79fe2944d6e3b732705

Comment: @Frank: Thank you! That sounds good. I will try this today.